# Оптимизация вложенного запроса sql

Tags: sql, запрос-в-запросе

Прошу дать совет в построении запроса на подсчет остатка на балансе по этапу работ за вычетом затрат на материалы/проч.расходы и стоимости работ внешних соисполнителей. Запрос, представленный ниже, считает корректно, я прошу сориентировать по корректности и правильности подхода.

```
 --Остаток по затратам на этап работ

SELECT Stages.BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors - 
  Executors_Stages.CostOfOutsideExecutors AS BalanceOrganization, Stages.IdStage
FROM
(SELECT          PriceWithTax - TravelCosts - MaterialCosts - OtherDirectCosts AS BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors, Stages.IdStage
 FROM            Stages
)Stages
JOIN
(SELECT         SUM (Executors_Stages.PriceWithTax) AS CostOfOutsideExecutors, Executors_Stages.IdStage
 FROM           Executors_Stages INNER JOIN
                Executors ON Executors_Stages.IdExecutor = Executors.IdExecutor
 WHERE          Executors.TypeExecutor = 'внешний'
 GROUP BY       Executors_Stages.IdStage
)Executors_Stages
ON Executors_Stages.IdStage=Stages.IdStage
```

Схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоимость этапа работ и затраты по нему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоимость работ соисполнителей:

[image: Стоимость работ соисполнителей:]

Приложение будет разрабатываться C#/EntityFramework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Корректность запроса.**

Ваш запрос не учитывает случаев, когда нет внешних соисполнителей!

Оператор `JOIN` - равнозначен уточнённому варианту `INNER JOIN`, и если для какого-то этапа договора (`Stages.idStage`) не нашлось соответствующих ему внешних соисполнителей (`Executors_Stages.idStage`), то в результатах будет просто отсутствовать строка, соответствующая данному этапу договора `idStage`.

Чтобы исправить проблему, достаточно сменить оператор `INNER JOIN` на оператор `LEFT OUTER JOIN` и взять в функцию `ISNULL` то, что Вы получаете из "правой части" запроса.

Запрос станет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT Stages.BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors - 
  ISNULL(Executors_Stages.CostOfOutsideExecutors, 0) AS BalanceOrganization, Stages.IdStage
FROM
(SELECT          PriceWithTax - TravelCosts - MaterialCosts - OtherDirectCosts AS BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors, Stages.IdStage
 FROM            Stages
 -- WHERE           [Status] = 'В работе'
)Stages
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT         SUM (Executors_Stages.PriceWithTax) AS CostOfOutsideExecutors, Executors_Stages.IdStage
 FROM           Executors_Stages INNER JOIN
                Executors ON Executors_Stages.IdExecutor = Executors.IdExecutor
 WHERE          Executors.TypeExecutor = 'внешний'
 GROUP BY       Executors_Stages.IdStage
)Executors_Stages
ON Executors_Stages.IdStage=Stages.IdStage
```

**2. Группировка данных.**

Если Вы захотите отобрать данные не по всем договорам таблицы `Stages`, а только по их части, то "правая часть" запроса (которая с группировкой) всё равно может обработать всю таблицу `Executors_Stages`. Если она окажется достаточно велика (порядка сотен тысяч записей) - то быстродействие запроса сильно радовать не будет.

В данном случае, можно реорганизовать запрос следующим образом:

```
SELECT
    BalanceOrganization = ( s.PriceWithTax - s.TravelCosts - s.MaterialCosts - s.OtherDirectCosts ) - ISNULL(SUM(es.PriceWithTax), 0),
    s.idStage
FROM
    Stages s
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        Executors_Stages es
        INNER JOIN Executors e ON ( es.idExecutor = e.idExecutor )
    )
    ON ( s.idStage = es.idStage ) AND ( e.TypeExecutor = 'внешний' )
-- WHERE
--   ( s.[Status] = 'В работе' )
GROUP BY
    s.idStage, s.PriceWithTax, s.TravelCosts, s.MaterialCosts, s.OtherDirectCosts
```

В этом варианте набор полей для группировки выглядит несколько дико, но MSSQL-серверу, как правило, уже "хватает ума" понять - реально группировка идёт только по полю `s.idStage`.

**3. Первичный ключ для `Executors_Stages`**

Очень похоже, что:

- на первичный ключ достаточно колонки `idExecStages`
- а колонки `idStage`+`idExecutor` (именно в таком порядке) можно ограничить составным уникальным индексом

Впрочем, по данному пункту могу и ошибаться

**4. Избавление от "странной" группировки в MS SQL SERVER**

Используя более современный синтаксис TRANSACT-SQL, с конструкцией CROSS/OUTER APPLY, можно выкрутиться следующим образом:

```
SELECT
    BalanceOrganization = BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors - ISNULL(CostOfOutsideExecutors, 0),
    s.IdStage
FROM
(
    SELECT
        BalanceWithoutOutsideExecutors = PriceWithTax - TravelCosts - MaterialCosts - OtherDirectCosts,
        idStage
    FROM
        Stages
    --WHERE
    --  ( [Status] = 'В работе' )
) s
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        CostOfOutsideExecutors = SUM(es.PriceWithTax)
    FROM
        Executors_Stages es
        INNER JOIN Executors e ON ( es.idExecutor = e.idExecutor )
    WHERE
        ( es.idStage = s.idStage ) AND
        ( e.TypeExecutor = 'внешний' )
) es
```

К сожалению, данный вариант будет эффективен только тогда, когда из таблицы `Stages` выбирается мало записей.

В противном случае, если выбирать всю таблицу `Stages`, данный вариант может оказаться хуже в быстродействии, чем традиционные `JOIN`-конструкции.

Comment: Подскажите, а в больших системах логику выборки строк по конкретному этапу (задавать idStage) логичнее переносить в логику работы программы(в моем случаее с помощью EntityFramework) или делать запросы к БД?

Comment: А если приведенный выше запрос необходимо использовать в представлении данных, получается в GROUP BY попадут все поля для отображения. Есть подозрение, что это не очень корректно, хотя и работает...

Comment: Подозреваю, что `Entity Framework` будет предпочитать вариант `Left Join`, так что даже в "больших системах" должно работать хорошо. Моё понимание `Entity Framework` пока ограниченно, поэтому рекомендую "доверять, но проверять" (видел где-то в `Entity Framework` свойство, позволяющее увидеть текст запроса; в крайнем случае, попробуйте `Sql Profiler`, чтобы "подглядеть").

Comment: Да, я субъективно согласен, что не очень корректно задавать такой список полей в группировке. Но избежать его можно, если использовать CROSS/OUTER APPLY. Отредактировал ответ - добавлен пункт 4 с новым вариантом запроса