# Присоединение результата сложного запроса к таблице или несколько полей в GROUP BY

Tags: sql, view, group-by, запрос-в-запросе

В дополнение к [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936252/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-sql/936308#936308)
Задача прицепить вычисленное в сложном запросе значение к таблице Stages для построения View.

Мне кажется, что использование GROUP BY по всем полям для отображения неоптимально, хотя по сути результат запрос дает правильный. Прошу разъяснить подход и в каких случаях им можно пользоваться.

```
SELECT        s.PriceWithTax - s.TravelCosts - s.MaterialCosts - 
              s.OtherDirectCosts - ISNULL(SUM(es.PriceWithTax), 0) AS BalanceOrganization, s.IdStage, s.IdContract,                          s.NumberOfStage, 
              s.Status, s.StartDate, s.EndDate, s.PriceWithTax, 
              s.PriceWithoutTax, s.TravelCosts, 
              s.MaterialCosts, s.OtherDirectCosts, s.CommentOtherCosts, s.Note, 
              s.TaxOfAllStage, s.PriceWithoutTaxOfAllStage
FROM          dbo.Executors_Stages AS es INNER JOIN
              dbo.Executors AS e ON es.IdExecutor = 
              e.IdExecutor RIGHT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.Stages AS s ON es.IdStage = s.IdStage AND 
              e.TypeExecutor = 'внешний'
GROUP BY      s.IdStage, s.PriceWithTax, s.TravelCosts, s.MaterialCosts, 
              s.OtherDirectCosts, s.IdContract, s.NumberOfStage, s.Status, 
              s.StartDate, s.EndDate, s.PriceWithoutTax, s.CommentOtherCosts, 
              s.Note, s.TaxOfAllStage, 
              s.PriceWithoutTaxOfAllStage
```

Comment: Если запрос в конечном виде именно такой как тут, то варианты из старого вопроса с подготовкой сумм в подзапросе в from выглядит лучше. Но если начать накладывать дополнительные условия на stages, что бы получить только часть данных - то тогда текущий вариант выглядит более производительным. А вообще последнее слово все равно за оптимизатором, надо посмотреть планы выполнения реальных запросов и что то тогда решать.

Comment: @Mike то есть много полей в GROUP BY по которым по факту ничего не группируется это не покушение на "святое" и такие запросы тоже практикуются? Или их стоит избегать и пересмотреть логику структуры БД?

Comment: Да, практикуются конечно, тут другого выхода все равно нет. А как конкретно оптимизатор выполнит группировку - это в общем то его дело. Я бы на его месте заметил что есть уникальное поле id и не добавлял бы в набор для сортировки все поля. И такие продвинутые БД как ms sql или oracle наверняка об этом то же позаботились. Но если вдруг нет и вы заметите сильную деградацию времени именно из за группировки, то заключите поля в max(). Хотя я сомневаюсь, что это быстрее, но всякое может быть

Comment: Просто из за наличия такого запроса пересматривать структуру БД явно не стоит. она выглядит корректной. Но если вдруг видите, что таких запросов много и они сильно тормозят и система плохо справляется. И при этом операций выборки гораздо больше, чем обновлений, то тогда можно уже рассматривать варианты с денормализацией структуры, например с внесением готовой суммы в stages и ведение ее триггерами

Comment: @Mike благодарю за комментарий, подскажите. в текущем запросе, если должно быть еще одно поле в этом представлении, где вычисляется баланс за вычетом всех соисполнителей (без AND e.TypeExecutor = 'внешний') как его правильнее добавить в текущее представление?

Comment: Убрать это условие из join. В верхней части запроса, если все еще надо считать отдельно сумму именно по внешним то делать `sum(case when e.typeexecutor='внешний' then es.PriceWithTax else 0 end)`

Comment: @Mike интересно Ваше мнение, смотрите в этой задаче требуется вычислять балансы организации, баланс за вычетом соисполнителей, баланс за вычетом внешних соисполнителей и сумму этого баланса по всем этапам работ, и дале много подытогов по работам в разрезе отделов, соисполнителей, стоимости работ, всех балансов и т.д.  И для всего использую вычисляемые поля, но как альтернатива в голове держу вариант с использованием полей и переносом расчетов в логику программы. Может что-то посоветуете по выбору подхода (вычисляемые поля/запросы или обычные/логика в ПО) или может посоветуете что почитать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88783/discussion-between-spiffo-and-mike).